# Custom jQuery Dropdown not firing with appended options

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, append, html-select

sorry if this is a simple one, I'm very new to jQuery.

I'm using a custom dropdown in place of select boxes. Here is the script:

```
function DropDown(el) {
            this.dd = el;
            this.parentid = this.dd.attr('id');
            this.placeholder = this.dd.children('span');
            this.opts = this.dd.find('ul.dropdown > li');
            this.val = '';
            this.index = -1;
            this.initEvents();
        }
        DropDown.prototype = {
            initEvents : function() {
                var obj = this;

                obj.dd.on('click', function(event){
                    $(this).toggleClass('active');
                    return false;
                });
                obj.opts.on('click',function(){
                    var opt = $(this);
                    obj.val = opt.text();
                    obj.index = opt.index();
                    if(obj.parentid == "dd"){ //brand
                    $('#brand').val(obj.val);
                    $("#brand").trigger('change')
                    } else if (obj.parentid == "dd3") { //availibility
                    $('#availibility').val(obj.val);
                    $("#availibility").trigger('change')
                    }
                    obj.placeholder.text(obj.val);
                });
            },
            getValue : function() {
                return this.val;
            },
            getIndex : function() {
                return this.index;
            }
        }

        $(function() {

            var dd = new DropDown( $('#dd') );
            var dd2 = new DropDown( $('#dd2') );
            var dd3 = new DropDown( $('#dd3') );

            $(document).click(function() {
                // all dropdowns
                $('.wrapper-dropdown-1').removeClass('active');
            });

        });
```

This works perfectly fine, but one of the dropdowns '#dd2' has different options added to it via .append()

The click event doesn't fire on these new options - any suggestions..?

Comment: Check if you are adding new dropdown with the same "ID". If so then your jquery event won't work as ID should be unique for a html page

Comment: If you are dynamically adding a new dropdown with different ID then you need to delegate the event to the new id. See how to delegate event in jquery for more help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think "obj.opts.on('click',function(){...})" is the problem;
I prefer

```
obj.dd.on('click', '.ul.dropdown > li', function() {
    //do your job here!
    var opt = $(this);
    obj.val = opt.text();
    obj.index = opt.index();
    if(obj.parentid == "dd"){ //brand
        $('#brand').val(obj.val);
        $("#brand").trigger('change')
    } else if (obj.parentid == "dd3") { //availibility
        $('#availibility').val(obj.val);
        $("#availibility").trigger('change')
    }
    obj.placeholder.text(obj.val);
});
```

because dynamic elment is not binding any event on it!